# Python: recursive fucntion to compute the sum of the difference of 2 vectors

Tags: python, recursion, matrix, vector, sum

I have a matrix `M` and the initial vector `v0`. I want to write a recursive function to perform `M*v_{i}` so that I can find `v_{i}` and `v_{i+1}` such that the sum of all the elements of the difference of the vectors is less than 0.45.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0]])
M = M.astype(float)
v0 = np.array([1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6])
v1 = np.dot(M, v0)
v2 = np.dot(M, v1)
v3 = np.dot(M, v2)
v4 = np.dot(M, v3)
v5 = np.dot(M, v4)
x = np.absolute(v4 - v5)
print(sum(x))
```

Here, my desired output is the value of `sum(x) = 0.42` and the vectors `v4` and `v5`. I have tried this so far and got stuck.

```py
def diff_sum(M, v):
    v1 = np.dot(M, v)
    x = np.absolute(v - v1)
    x = sum(x)
    if x < 0.45:
        return (x, v, v1)
    else:
        diff_sum(M, np.dot(M, v1))
        return (x, v, v1)
```

Comment: Recursion with numpy? That's like mixing chalk and cheese, please don't :(

Comment: looks like you want a loop rather than a recursive function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need a recursive, but this is easily done with a loop:

```
def diff_sum(M,vi1):
    er=1
    while (er>0.45):
        vi=vi1.copy()
        vi1=M @ vi
        er=np.abs(vi1-vi).sum()
    return vi,vi1,er
vn1,vn,er=diff_sum(M,v0)
```